# Rails Foreign Key violation deleting has_many relationships with dependent destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, postgresql-9.5

I have a simple `has_many` relationship in a Rails 4.2 model:

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :nested_things, :inverse_of => :owner, :class_name => "Nested::Thing", :dependent => :destroy
end

class Nested::Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :inverse_of=>:nested_things
end
```

The models are considerably more complicated than this, with many other relationships.

When somebody tried to delete an `Owner` today, it failed, because there is a foreign key on the `nested_things` table:

```
> psql annoying_problem

psql (9.5.3)
Type "help" for help.

annoying_problem=# \d+ nested_things
                                                            Table "public.nested_things"
      Column      |            Type             |                           Modifiers                            | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id               | integer                     | not null default nextval('nested_things_id_seq'::regclass)     | plain    |              | 
 owner_id         | integer                     |                                                                | plain    |              | 

 Indexes:
    "nested_things_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ix_nested_things_on_owner_id" btree (owner_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "nested_things_owner_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES owners(id)
```

When the `owner` is deleted, its a time consuming process - locally this particular record generated a 109,000 line log file of all the SQL executed.  However, **the nested_things relationship causes the entire operation to abort because a foreign key check fails**.

Here is what seems to be the relevant part of the log file:

```
> grep -n nested_things delete-owner.txt 

....

109762: SQL (1.1ms)  DELETE FROM "nested_things" WHERE "nested_things"."id" = $1  [["id", 8665]]

109836: ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: 
        ERROR:  update or delete on table "owners" violates foreign key 
        constraint "nested_things_owner_id_fk" on table "nested_things"

109837: DETAIL:  Key (id)=(6343) is still referenced from table "nested_things".
```

There is only one nested_things entry for this owner.  **What can cause a :dependent => :destroy relationship in Rails, to delete the dependent relationship, but fail the foreign key check?**

Comment: I thought maybe the index was corrupt, but re-indexing didn't change anything.

Comment: This isn't the first foreign key checked when I try to delete from the table directly.

Comment: Deleting another owner record that also has nested_things works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer was a default scope on the has_many relationships that wasn't accounted for in the destroy.

Comment: How did you eliminate it? Either did you removed default_scope, or solve it another way?

Comment: It looks like I added a before_destroy to the model where the foreign key violation occurred that deleted the objects not present in the default scope.  The default scope was `enabled: true` so my before_destroy deleted everything with enabled false, or enabled nil:

  ```before_destroy {
    NestedThings.unscoped.where(:owner_id => self.id, :enabled => [nil, false]).destroy_all
  }```